# How do i write a string letter by letter using concatenation in python

Tags: python, string, time, operating-system

I currently have a way to write a string letter by letter but when i try and include more arguments it gives me the error that it was expecting 1 and not 3

I used this to define

```
def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

i then tried this code:

```
delay_print("You have" ,lives, "lives left")
```

and then go the error:

```
    delay_print("You have" ,lives, "lives left")
TypeError: delay_print() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you pass 3 arguments. The comma separates the arguments a function recieves. what you can do is

```
delay_print("You have" + lives + "lives left")
```

or more fancy with the f-string syntax.

```
delay_print(f"You have {lives} lives left")
```

Comment: The lives are integers though so it wont work
edit: nevermind i tried using f-string syntax

Comment: `delay_print(f"You have {str(lives)} lives left")` then. But it also should work with integers. Python automatically does the casting.

Comment: Is there any way i would be able to use this in a `input`?

Comment: Do you mean a user input? You can just set the variable with `lives = int(input())`. But you have to handle invalid inputs. 
If I got you wrong please elaborate the question further.

Comment: as in `choice = str(input("Which path will you take?")` but delaying each character without needing to print and then put `choice = input()`

Comment: There is no way to control the prompt of `input()` with the parameters in such a way. What I would do is to call your function and then the empty `input()` function. However this could lead to some weird behavior because you are writing directly to stdout. But thats another question. If my original answer helped you please mark it as the solving answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable number of arguments like this:

```
import sys
import time

def delay_print(*args):
    for s in args:
        for c in str(s):
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.25)

delay_print("You have ", 2, " lives left")
```

**Output:**

```
You have 2 lives left
```